# Copy from s3 to redshift

Tags: database, amazon-s3, mysql-workbench, amazon-redshift

I am loading data to redshift from s3, using MANIFEST to specify load because I have to load 8k files (total dataset size ~1TB)

I am using SQLWorkbench to load this dataset, I am setting MAXERROR = 100000, but actual error occurring is greater than 100000 (MAXERROR=100000). I think SQLWorkbench had MAXERROR limit to 100000.

Is there any better way to do this ? any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you (1) set `MAXERROR` to a higher value, (2) split the load into multiple batches (multiple manifests), or (3) fix part of the errors (e.g. schema-related issues)? For the latter, `STL_LOAD_ERRORS` has information on what exactly went wrong.

Comment: (1) I tried to set MAXERROR > 100000, but I think SQLWorkbench has MAX value for MAXERROR is 100000. I don know how to set that higher than 100000. (2) I have already splitted load (8K files into manifests of 500 files/manifests)still having same problem. (3) Some of the record in the data is not confined to schema but I don't care much if those records doesn't load in to redshift. Is there any other way to load this data ?

Comment: I checked STL_LOAD_ERRORS and noticed there are only two types of error (1) "Delimited value missing end quote" and (2) "Invalid digit, Value 'c', Pos 0, Type: Long" , any help to fix this ?

Comment: Error 1: are the fields supposed to be quoted? If not, disable quotes. Error 2: you are trying to load a value with a letter into a numeric column. Load it into e.g. a VARCHAR column instead. If you need it as an integer, load it into a staging table first and convert from there.

Comment: (1) Some of the fields are quoted but i am specifying REMOVEQUOTES to get rid of it , (2) This I have fixed by changing datatype from BIGINT to VARCHAR, because actual field is timestamp:BIGINT, but some of the records have string instead of INT.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually have more than 100,000 errors in your data being imported I would suggest you need to go back to the source and correct the files. If that's not possible then you could try loading the data into a table with the problematic columns set to VARCHAR(MAX) and then you can convert them inside Redshift.

Comment: Yes i did the same, loaded the data with varchar then deleted recorders which are not appropriate to schema and then converted the datatype